# How to spawn expect process with complicated syntax?

Tags: expect

In expect it is possible to spawn a process like,

```
spawn /usr/bin/sftp "$uri" /home/user/dest
```

Writing it like this makes things really simple, it will be a one liner. However, I am trying to replicate this for upload. This is a bit more complicated,

```
spawn /usr/bin/sftp "$uri" <<< $'put "$source"'
```

Most likely the issue is that this is bash code and not a single command. Is there a way to spawn something like this in expect, or will I have to do it the long way? I also tried with braces, to no success.

BR
Patrik

Comment: How are you running this? in a bash script or an expect script>

Comment: @Inian Running pure expect, but it will always be run from a bash shell.

Comment: I've always found perl's `Expect.pm` module (and the various protocol-specific modules like `Net::SSH`, `Net::Telnet`, and `Net::SFTP`, etc) to be a lot more useful and easier to work with than `expect` itself.   Amongst other benefits, there's no need for messing around with shell quoting or escaping, just use perl vars where they're needed.    Python has similar capabilities with, e.g., the `pexpect` library.

Comment: Also, I think it's a waste of time learning a single-purpose language like `expect`, especially when you'll use it only rarely.  IMO that time is better spent learning or improving your skill with a general purpose language like perl or python, which you'll use far more often for many and varied tasks.

Comment: @cas not sure if "improving in perl" is completely accurate. I managed to get fairly fluent in perl in about 3 weeks (though this knowledge may not extend to big perl apps, if there ever is a point for these). Anyway, expect is very useful for short scripts where you just want to connect to a remote system, do just two things and terminate. I cannot say my expect skills are the result of more than about 8 hours of learning and this is sufficient for almost anything I use expect for.

Comment: any time you use a language, there's a chance you'll get better at it. I've been writing perl and awk and other stuff since the 90s and I still get better at them. familiarity breeds proficiency :).   I learned expect in the early 90s too (there wasn't any alternative other than write-your-own back then).  I've needed to use expect or something expect-like perhaps 5 or 10 (definitely less than 20) times since then. For me, learning expect was a waste of time, I just don't use it often enough.   I use the other languages daily or near-daily - well worth getting more practice as often as i can.

Comment: I learnt tcl too. I don't think I've used it at all since around '97 (tcl + tk was, at the time, looking like it was going to be a good, quick way to write GUI apps or front-ends on linux).   There's nothing i can do in tcl that I can't do easier or better in perl or python.  I know some people still love it, but for me it's effectively a dead language.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is embarrasing. As soon as I formulated the questions the solution began to clarify. Of course it is possible to spawn a bash shell and run whatever commands I want there,

```
spawn /bin/bash
send "/usr/bin/sftp \"$uri\" <<< $\'put \"$source\"\'\r"
```

Anyway, for all it's worth there might be more people running into this problem so I will post a solution to this instead of removing the post.

Comment: Note, you can also use `{...}` to quote a string and it will not need any special backslash escapes (except for nested `{}`). See the section *[6] Braces* in [tcl](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Dodekalogue)